Buttons rest within scroll limits
There is a block with limited width. It has buttons. The sum of the button widths is wider than the width of the parent.
A scroll appears. When you press a button, it should scroll in the direction it needs until it (the pressed button) is in the center of the parent block.
Scrolling seems to work, but the buttons are not centered correctly, apparently because the outermost element rests on the scroll border or block border and this prevents further scrolling.
It turns out that only the 4th and 5th buttons are in the center, although they are already almost in the center (and to be honest, I’m not sure that they are doing everything right either).
The remaining buttons twitch slightly but do not become centered.


// Get all the buttons within the container
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

// Add event listener to each button
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Remove the "active" class from all buttons
    buttons.forEach((btn) => btn.classList.remove('active'));

    // Add the "active" class to the clicked button
    button.classList.add('active');

    // Scroll the container to the center of the clicked button
    const container = button.parentElement;
    const containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
    const buttonWidth = button.offsetWidth;
    const buttonOffset = button.offsetLeft;
    const scrollAmount = buttonOffset - (containerWidth / 2) + (buttonWidth / 2);
    container.scrollLeft = scrollAmount;
  });
});
.block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.button.active {
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
}
<div class="block">
  <button class="button">Button 1</button>
  <button class="button">Button 2</button>
  <button class="button">Button 3</button>
  <button class="button">Button 4</button>
  <button class="button">Button 5</button>
  <button class="button">Button 6</button>
</div>



I am just learning. I haven't tried much. And I barely wrote this code 
